# .htaccess redirecting url error obtained when index.php file removing from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm having some problems with the .htaccess file.i want to redirect and avoiding index.php file from the url.

my first url is

```
 www.hestiamedicare.com/web/index.php/contact
```

above link convert to

```
 www.hestiamedicare.com/web/contact.
```

Comment: What rule have you tried for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's like Yii framework web struct.
If true, just enable pretty url from urlManager

```
'enablePrettyUrl'=>true
```

if not, use this code in .htaccess to rewrite all request (which do not directly to a file or folder) to index.php :

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

then handle request url from your index file.